# Если пояснение на пояснении, какие требуются знаки? Чтоб не запутаться вконец?

Tags: пунктуация

> Философствования на темы Времени, устройства Вселенной, богословия и
>   *икономии* (что с греческого – искусство управления домом), то есть учение о действиях Божиих в отношении мира и человека: о Творении,
>   Промысле, Воплощении, Спасении и так далее и тому подобное,
>   запечатлены во фресках обители кардинала, в так называемом *Готическом
>   зале*.

Курсив автора.

Главное предложение: *Философствования запечатлены.*

Как быть с остальной пунктуацией?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Знаки поставлены верно, но предложение перегружено этими знаками и читается с трудом (а это тоже недостаток). Как вариант, можно использовать **вставную конструкцию с тире**:

Философствования на темы Времени, устройства Вселенной, богословия и икономии (что с греческого – искусство управления домом) **– другими словами, учение о действиях Божиих в отношении мира и человека: о Творении, Промысле, Воплощении, Спасении и так далее и тому подобное –**  запечатлены во фресках обители кардинала, в так называемом Готическом зале.

Comment: А почему перед *другими словами* зап-тире? Одного тире нам не хватит? (А так - всё красиво, спасибо!)

Comment: В общем, я пририсовала вторую зап для пущей симметрии - после *и тому подобное*.

Comment: Надо убрать запятую перед "другими словами". Это тема обособленного оборота в начале вставки, но по основным правилам (Розенталь, Лопатин) запятой там нет. Где-то я читала про эту запятую, но  не могу найти где, поэтому  обе запятые не ставим, только тире.

Comment: Ага-угу! Мерсю!!!